# Cambiar parte de URLs con htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

He probado muchas formas y no logro encontrar algo que solvente mi problema. Les explico.

Actualmente tengo una estructura así:

```
index.php
dashboard.php
perfil.php
----/root
--------/views
--------/core
```

Desde **dashboard.php** yo entro a los folders `root/views` para incluir el menú único del sitio, el footer y todas las partes que forman la vista. Hasta ahí todo bien, la url de **dashboard.php** es `http://localhost/proyecto/dashboard` y se ve normal.

Pero, si sigo así, me voy a llenar de archivos en el root del sitio, archivos para el perfil, datos, validar cosas entre otros, así que pensé en meter a **dashboard.php** dentro de la carpeta `views` del proyecto y luego cambiar el aspecto de las url por medio de `htaccess` pero no logro encontrar la regla ideal para hacer el cambio de `http://localhost/proyecto/root/views/dashboard` a `http://localhost/proyecto/dashboard`

He intentado con el siguiente `htaccess`

```
# Quitar extencion de las URL
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
# FIN quitar extencion de las URL

############################################

# Da error Not Found
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule ^root/views/dashboard/$ dashboard/ [L]

# No hace nada
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /root/views/dashboard=$1

# No hace nada
RewriteRule ^dashboard/$ /root/views/dashboard/ [QSA,L]

# No hace nada
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ root/views/dashboard/$1dashboard/ [L]

# No hace nada
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/dashboard/$ /root/views/dashboard/ [L,QSA]
```

Y como podrán ver por los comentarios, ninguna forma me ha hecho poder cambiar mi url. ¿Que es lo que tengo mal?

---

He dejado el `htaccess` así

```
# Quitar extencion de las URL
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
# FIN quitar extencion de las URL


# No hace nada
RewriteRule ^proyecto/root/views/dashboard proyecto/dashboard? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^proyecto/root/views/dashboard /proyecto/dashboard? [R=301,L]
```

La `R=301` significa que hay que realizar una redirección `301`. La `L` significa que cuando se ejecute esta directiva, el servidor ignorará el resto del archivo `.htaccess`

Además ten en cuenta que sólo una vez en el archivo debes de indicar `RewriteEngine on` , no es necesario indicarla varias veces si no la desactivas nunca.

Comment: No hace nada. He puesto el `htaccess` otra vez, quitando lo del `RewriteEngine on` que mencionas.

Comment: He usado este tester https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=776c721c-51c5-4ad6-a598-29ae616ff81c con las url que proporcionas. Revisa que no haya otra regla general que esté aplicando en otro .htaccess

Comment: En el tester funciona pero en mi proyecto no. Tengo otros proyectos en localhost pero no creo que eso afecte, reinicié apache, probé en otros navegadores y nada, sigo viendo la url con los folders. Se debe hacer algo más a parte de la regla htaccess??

Comment: Creo que entonces apache no está usando tu .htaccess Revisa esta pregunta para que estés seguro que lo está usando https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769880/why-is-the-apache2-htaccess-file-not-being-read-options-indexes-in-htacce

Comment: Esto sería aunque las otras reglas si sean aplicadas? Porque quitar las extensiones si que lo hace